# How to stream binary data to standard output in .NET?

Tags: .net, interop

I'm trying to stream binary data to the standard output in .NET. However you can only write char using the Console class. I want to use it with [redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(Unix)). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the output stream using `Console.OpenStandardOutput`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some data"));
        using (Stream console = Console.OpenStandardOutput()) {
            data.CopyTo(console);
        }
    }
```